# module `testavg` is in file 'testavg.d' which cannot be read d

Tags: d

Every-time, I try to run a program it gives me an error similar to this. I haven't done anything other than download it. I tried to reinstall it and got the same results. It is on a windows 10 computer.

[image]

```
Error: module `testavg` is in file 'testavg.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos
import path[1] = C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\druntime\import
```

https://dlang.org/download.html

Comment: Can you link us to the program? I wanna see the source myself. (it looks like a simple file not found thing; maybe the name is supposed to be something else)

Comment: https://dlang.org/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the D compiler can't find the source file `testavg.d`. Either change directory to where the file is and run the same command, or give a full path to the source file: `dmd C:/my/d/source/files/testavg.d` (replace the path to the testavg.d with the actual path)